Having Trouble making a Simple Dress Up Game in Pygame
I'm trying to make a simple dress up game where there are three buttons. Depending on which button you press, you can put either a pink, blue, or green shirt on a mannequin.
However, my problem is that the game doesn't properly replace one shirt with another when you click on a different shirt's button. I want to make it so that you can change which shirt you want the mannequin to wear whenever you press the corresponding button.
Here is my current code:
            import pygame

            pygame.init()


            #screen window's hight and width
            winW = 600
            winH = 600

            #game window
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((winW,winH))

            #game title
            pygame.display.set_caption("Dress Up Game")



            #image maniquinn to put cloths on
            lady = pygame.image.load("DUG/ladybase.webp")
            lady = pygame.transform.scale(lady,(460,560))

            #images of the cloths
            blueShirt = pygame.image.load("DUG/blue shirt.jpg")
            blueShirt = pygame.transform.scale(blueShirt,(60,60))
            greenShirt = pygame.image.load("DUG/greenShirt.jpg")
            greenShirt = pygame.transform.scale(greenShirt,(60,60))

            pinkShirt = pygame.image.load("DUG/pinkShirt.jpg")
            pinkShirt = pygame.transform.scale(pinkShirt,(60,60))






            class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

                def __init__(self,x,y,image):
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                    
                    
                    #creates a rectangle out of an image and gives it a x and y
                    self.image = image
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.x = x
                    self.rect.y = y
                    self.clicked = False #will let the function know if the button's been clicked
                    
                
                def update(self):

                    action = False #whatever action that will occur in the main code

                    #get the mouse's position
                    mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                    if self.rect.collidepoint(mousePosition):

                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                            self.clicked = True
            
                    if self.clicked == True:
                        action = True

                    win.blit(self.image,self.rect)
                    return action

            #the buttons
            pinkShirtButton = Button(20,100,pinkShirt)
            blueShirtButton = Button(80,100,blueShirt)
            greenShirtButton = Button(132,100,greenShirt)

            #game loop
            run = True

            while run == True:

                win.fill((255,0,0))

                win.blit(lady,(280,90)) #draws the manniquinn on screen
                
                if pinkShirtButton.update(): #if you press the button
                    
                    win.blit(pinkShirt,(500,500)) #the pink shirt goes on the maniquinn
                
                    

                if blueShirtButton.update(): #if you press the button
                
                    win.blit(blueShirt,(500,300)) #the blue shirt goes on the maniquinn
                    
                    
                    
                if greenShirtButton.update(): #if you press the button
                    
                    win.blit(greenShirt,(500,100)) #the green shirt goes on the maniquinn
                    
                    
                

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        run = False
                    
                pygame.display.update()
                
            pygame.quit()

I tried to make the shirts that weren't currently picked to go on the mannequin disappear by making them go off the screen, but that didn't seem to affect anything.
I'm not really sure what to do at this point.

Can you fix the indentation and add some code fences in an [edit]? It's very hard to figure out what your code actually looks like.

Welcome to SO, we may be able to help you if you can explain your problem more. Also, I agree with @AndrewYim, probably you should add a if __name__ == '__main__': check. I think I will edit your post to fix that.

It seems like I can't edit now though, because there are too many pending edits. I will come back later.

It seems like you never set button.clicked to False aside from the Button.__init__() method. So once clicked, it will always stay True.

You should use Sprite Groups to manage your sprites. See this answer for collision detection.
To toggle visibility, you can use a special sprite group that can only contain one sprite and assign the associated sprite.
Here's untested code based on your code:
import pygame

class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #creates a rectangle out of an image and gives it a x and y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        pass

pygame.init()
#screen window's hight and width
winW = 600
winH = 600
#game window
win = pygame.display.set_mode((winW,winH))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#game title
pygame.display.set_caption("Dress Up Game")
#image of mannequin to put cloths on
lady = pygame.image.load("images/mannequin.webp")
lady = pygame.transform.scale(lady,(460,560))
#images of the cloths
blueShirt = pygame.image.load("images/blue shirt.jpg")
blueShirt = pygame.transform.scale(blueShirt,(60,60))
greenShirt = pygame.image.load("images/greenShirt.jpg")
greenShirt = pygame.transform.scale(greenShirt,(60,60))
pinkShirt = pygame.image.load("images/pinkShirt.jpg")
pinkShirt = pygame.transform.scale(pinkShirt,(60,60))
# coordinates
shirt_position = (500, 500)
mannequin_position = (280, 90) 
#the buttons
pinkShirtButton = Button(20,100,pinkShirt)
blueShirtButton = Button(80,100,blueShirt)
greenShirtButton = Button(132,100,greenShirt)
# groups
buttons = pygame.sprite.Group()
for button in [pinkShirtButton, blueShirtButton, greenShirtButton]
    buttons.add(button)
selected_shirt = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
#game loop
run = True
while run == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            for button in buttons:
                if button.rect.collide_point(event.pos):
                    # create a sprite to draw based on the button image
                    shirt = Button(*shirt_position, button.image)
                    selected_shirt.add(shirt)
    win.fill("red")
    win.blit(lady, mannequin_position) #draws the mannequin on screen
    buttons.draw(win)
    selected_shirt.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit to 60 FPS
pygame.quit()

In future, please construct a Minimum Reproducible Example so it's easier to help you. E.g., for questions like this, create your sprite images programmatically, such as drawing a triangle for a shirt, this way no external resources are required.
